# delete (this) pointer in destructor

Tags: c++

I wrote the program just to check what happens if we delete this pointer in the destructor of the classs. Here is my code

```
 class xxx{
    public: xxx(){cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;}
            ~xxx(){cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;delete(this);}  //deleting the 'this' pointer
 };
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    xxx *x1=new xxx();
    delete x1;
    return 0;
 }
```

When I run this program it results in indefinite loop printing "desctructor called".

What is the relation between `delete` operator and destructor function? Also what happens when you use `delete this` in the destructor?

Comment: Is there even a question here ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`this->~destructor` is called, then `delete(this)` will will again call `this->~destructor` thus results in calling function indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you get an infinite loop (or perhaps a stack overflow). `delete` calls the destructor before deallocating the memory, so if that in turn tries to delete the object that's already being deleted, then you're in a recursive death spiral.

The simple solution is: don't do that.

Comment: it's not infinte , it's stack overflow

Comment: @Raxvan: Unless tail-call optimisation is applied.

Comment: Indeed in release it will optimize it, but not in debug (VS2013 at least).