# How can I delete the Error when creating pointers on C++? I this case I have to use raw pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, nodes

I'm trying to make a linked list with a pointer to a template class called Node:

```
template <typename T>
class llnode

{
public:
    T key;
    llnode<T> *prev, *next;

    llnode()
    {

    };

    llnode(const T &k, llnode<T> *w = NULL, llnode<T> *y = NULL) : key(k), prev(w), next(y){};

    ~llnode()
    {
        delete this;
    }
};
```

But, when I run the program this code in the `main` function

```
llnode<int> *node;
node->key = 6;
llnode<int> *node1;
node->key = 2;
```

I get the error message:

```
403 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to "NAME OF MY EXE".exe.stackdump
```

How can I create more nodes without getting the error?
It happens when I have 2 nodes created, but when I have 1 it does it right.

Comment: Your pointers are uninitialized.  You have no way of knowing _what_ they are pointing at.  So when you try to write to memory with `node->key = 6;` _anything_ could happen.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you need `delete this;` in destructor? It is not required and can lead to strange behaviour

Comment: Agree with the delete this comment. Deleting the instance already achieves this (if the instance was on the heap in the first place). the destructor is for deleting class members from the heap when the instance is deleted. You could possibly end up with infinite recursion of destructor calls by calling `delete this` in the destructor...

Comment: Also, are you intending to allocate this object on the stack and not the heap? because that is what you are doing, See the answer below which uses the `new` operator to return a heap address and initializes the pointer with that address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use them in main your pointers are not initializated. This ends in Undefined Behavior.

Do this:

```cpp
llnode<int> *node = new llnode<int>;
node->key = 6;
llnode<int> *node1 = new llnode<int>;
node->key = 2;
```

Also note that calling `delete this;` in the destructor causes an infinite loop (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273041/delete-this-pointer-in-destructor)). Remove the destructor and free the space manually or better use a Smart Pointers or RAII approach.

Comment: Please avoid adding spaces around `->`.  This only makes code less readable.

Comment: when i initializate pointers this way, Im getting the same error, when creating the second pointer of llnode.

Comment: Have you removed the destructor?

Comment: Yes, i have removed the delete from the destructor.

Comment: @ErickMurillo, this is the answer to the question as asked. I recommend poking at the new problem for a while and then ask a new question if you're stuck. Make a [mre]. MRE is a really powerful debugging technique. Done right you're left with a really small program that is nothing but the bug. It's really easy to see the problem at that point, but you rarely need to get that far. After a few rounds of divide and conquer, the bug probably has too little space to hide.

Comment: You are not showing enough code in your question.  This answer 100% fixes any crashy problems with the code you provided.  Except, of course, if there's not enough memory to allocate these two nodes, which is far beyond the realms of unlikely.  Perhaps you have extended the typo/copy-paste error where you use `node` instead of `node1`.  Are you adding `node` to the list twice?  Are you assuming that `prev` and `next` are default-initialized to `nullptr`? (hint: they're uninitialized)

Comment: well I have debugged it and, and in my constructor I have put my `prev` and `next`, as `nullptr` too, also getting the same error, when I call the `constructor` of `llnode` for the second node (node1).
I will continue searching on the web for help.
thanks for the help provided.

Answer (score 3):

First, for

```
llnode<int> *node;
node->key = 6;
llnode<int> *node1;
node->key = 2;
```

your problem is that `node` is an uninitialized pointer. You should always initialize your pointers (or better, use smart pointers like `unique_ptr`). Try:

```
std::unique_ptr<llnode<int>> node = std::make_unique<llnode<int>>();
node->key = 6;
std::unique_ptr<llnode<int>> node1 = std::make_unique<llnode<int>>();
node->key = 2;
```

or better:

```
auto node = std::make_unique<llnode<int>>(6);
auto node1 = std::make_unique<llnode<int>>(2);
```

In general, this is very C-like C++. Raw pointers are hard to use correctly, particularly when it comes to exception safety. For that reason, I make an effort to never write `new` or `delete` ever. (There are places, but really, you want to avoid them.)

You can use `std::unique_ptr` to do cleanup (and initialization) for you. You can also default raw pointers to `nullptr`.

In C++11 and beyond, don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`, it's safer.

Consider something like this:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class llnode
{
public:
    T key;
    llnode<T>* prev = nullptr; // Raw pointer back
    std::unique_ptr<llnode<T>> next; // List owns it tail.

    llnode(const T &k = {}, 
           llnode<T> *w = nullptr,
           std::unique_ptr<llnode<T>> y = nullptr)
    : key(k), prev(w), next(std::move(y)) {}
};
```

When this node is deleted, the node pointed to by `next` (if `next != nullptr`) will also be deleted for you.

Often a doubly-linked linked list will have a separate type that hides the nodes from the user, maintaining access to the front and back. Then you can provide standard operations such as `list<T>.push_back(const T&)`.

Comment: The point is that I have to use raw pointers on this proyect, I know about smart ptrs, but in this case I need to use raw.

Comment: The question shows uninitialized pointers leading to a crash.  If this answer, as currently written, were adapted by the OP, what is to say that they won't now be dereferencing default-initialized unique pointers, still resulting in a crash?