# How to destruct the root node of binary tree as well?

Tags: binary-tree, destructor, heap-memory

I have got a binary volume hierarchies tree and its header file can be seen below:

```
class BvhNode {

    private:   
        BBox bBox;
        int depthOfNode;
        int order;
        bool isLeaf;
        bool createdEmpty;
        int leftOrRight;
    
        vector<BvhNode *> children;
        vector<glm::vec4> indices;

/* Other parts of the code....*/
};
```

During the construction, children nodes, just like the root node are allocated on the heap with the `new` operator:

`BvhNode* bvhNode = new BvhNode();`

Because of heap allocation, delete have to be called and user-defined destructor is also required.
Here is my destructor:

```
BvhNode::~BvhNode() {
  if(this->children.size()!=0){
       delete this->children.at(0);
       delete this->children.at(1);
   }
  //delete this;     //I tried this to delete root node, but it causes infinite loop.
}
```

Duing the debug, I have noticed that the every children node have garbage after calling the `delete` instruction. I guess this means that the data has been deallocated well. Unfortunately, the root node still has non-garbage data. I wanted to put `delete this;` at the end of destructor, but in this case, it will go into an infinite loop.

I have heard that smart pointers would be a better idea, but I am curious about the usual way.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `delete` will call the destructor before deallocating the memory. If you're inside the destructor, somebody presumably already called delete on that object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete (this) pointer in destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273041/delete-this-pointer-in-destructor)

Comment: If you're unsure, there are tools like `valgrind` that you can use to check whether you are freeing your memory correctly.

Comment: @dratenik Yeah, writing "delete this;" causes infinite loop as the other question mentions.  But then how can I deallocate data pointed by the root node?

Comment: I will check valgrind.

Comment: To go back to my initial comment: if you want `delete this` to clean the root node, why is the destructor being called in the first place with `this` set to `root` ? (or `bvhNode` in your case, btw having multiple things differing only in upper/lower case is not good naming practice, don't do that) Would that be because somebody outside the destructor called `delete root`? And that's how you clean the root node.

Comment: @dratenik Ok, I am getting it. The debugger showed me usual data in the case of root node and I supposed it had not been freed up. Writing "free bvhNode" instruction, it giving me double free error. So it is definitely freed up.