# Does `delete this` inside a destructor release an object create by `new`?

Tags: c++

I read that `delete this` is a legal statement, although an undesirable one. So I was creating a test example:

```
class test
{
public:
    test(){}
    ~test()
    {
        delete this;
    }
    
};
  
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  
    test* t = new test();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code with `valgrind --leak-check=full ./test` it shows that one of the two allocated bytes was lost.

> ```
> HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==23095==     in use at exit: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==23095==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,705 bytes allocated
> ==23095== 
> ==23095== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
> ==23095==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==23095==    by 0x1090B1: main (in /home/linux/Workspace/test)
> ==23095== 
> ==23095== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==23095==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==23095==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==23095==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==23095==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==23095==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ```

However when I put a `delete` statement in the main function, I get a segmentation fault because obviously the `delete this` statement has destroyed the object.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  
    test* t = new test();
    delete t; // segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain what `delete this` is doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete (this) pointer in destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273041/delete-this-pointer-in-destructor)

Comment: Nothing calls the destructor so `delete` never happens (if it did then `delete` would call the destructor again resulting in and infinite recursion or some other undefined behaviour). Don't use tricks, use smart pointers or in this simple example just avoid pointers completely and use an object

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah, so in the first example the destructor is never called and in the second example I get an infinite loop. This was just a learning exercise; I wouldn't do something like in production code.

Comment: Never use `delete this`, because it does not make any sense

Comment: @Slay never say never

Comment: `delete this;` in a destructor is automatically an error. In a destructor, your object is already being destroyed, and `delete this;` will try to destroy it again. There is no scenario where this is correct.

Comment: @Slay `delete this;` is usually a bad idea, but it is not necessary illegal code. See [isocpp's FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this).